# Category Specific Archive

Tags: categories, archives

I'm trying to display a monthly archive but only for a certain category. How can I do this?

Comment: You should be able to query for that in the URL, ie. `example.com/?cat=1&monthnum=01` .. where `1` and `01` would be the respective category ID and month number.

Answer (score 1):

I found a plugin that does the job.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-category-archive/installation/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code for widget that I just build for one of my client:

```
<?php 
/*
 * Archive Widget
 * 
 */

class cb_archive_widget extends WP_Widget {

    /*
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    function cb_archive_widget() {
        parent::WP_Widget(
            false, // Base ID
            'Custom Archive Widget', // Name
            array( 'description' =>  'Use this widget to place Specific Archives depending on category selection', ) // Args
        );
    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        global $cat;
        $cat = $instance['arc_cat'];
        $catID = get_cat_ID( $cat );
        $arc_title = $instance['arc_title'];

        //add the archive filters
        add_filter('getarchives_where','ik_custom_archives_where',10,3);
        add_filter('getarchives_join','ik_custom_archives_join',10,3);

        //add custom SQL to the archives widget JOIN clause
        function ik_custom_archives_join($sql){
            global $wpdb;

            $sql = $sql . "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) ";
            $sql = $sql . "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) ";

            return $sql;
        }

        //add custom SQL to the archives widget WHERE clause
        function ik_custom_archives_where($sql){

            global $wpdb;
            global $cat;
            $catID = get_cat_ID( $cat );

            $sql = "WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' ";
            $sql = $sql . "AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN ($catID)";

            return $sql;
        }


        $checked = $instance['arc_count'];
        if ($checked == 'on') { $counter_arc = 1; } else { $counter_arc = 0; };
        $args = array(
                'show_post_count' => $counter_arc,
            );
        ?>

        <!-- Display HTML -->
        <?php
        echo $before_widget;
        echo $before_title . $arc_title . $after_title;
        ?>
        <ul>
            <?php wp_get_archives($args); ?>
        </ul>
        <?php 
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['arc_title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['arc_title'] );
        $instance['arc_cat'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['arc_cat'] );
        $instance['arc_count'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['arc_count'] );
        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $arc_title = $instance['arc_title'];
        $arc_checked = $instance['arc_count']; ?>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('arc_title'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Add Title:' ); ?></label><br/> 
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($arc_title); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('arc_title'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('arc_title'); ?>" /><br/>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('arc_cat'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Choose Category:' ); ?></label><br/> 
        <?php 

            $args = array(
                'style'              => 'list',
                'show_count'         => 1,
                'depth'              => 1,
                'taxonomy'           => 'category',
                'walker'             => null
            );
            $test = get_categories( $args );
            ?>
            <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('arc_cat'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('arc_cat'); ?>">
            <?php
            foreach( $test as $category) {
                if ($category->category_parent == 0) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $category->name?>" <?php if($category->name == $instance['arc_cat']) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $category->name ?></option>
        <?php   }
        }
        ?>
        </select><br/>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('arc_count'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show Count:' ); ?></label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" <?php checked( (bool) $arc_checked, true ); ?> name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('arc_count'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('arc_count'); ?>"/>

        <?php 
    }
}// register widget

add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("cb_archive_widget");') );?>
```

Copy and paste this into your theme functions.php file. Then chose this new widget and chose category that you want to use for archive.

btw. this is only for parrent categories, if u want to see all categories, just remove line if ($category->category_parent == 0)