# wp_get_archives for a specific category?

Tags: customization, wp-get-archives

I've been pulling my hair out on this one - I need to hard code in `wp_get_archives()` for a specific category into a template.

This post was useful:

[Category Specific Archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13288/category-specific-archive)

but, as with all the plugins I've found so far, they don't work with WP 3.1 (or you need to hack the core files which I obviously don't want to do).

Is there another solution I'm not aware of? Maybe a method by creating a separate loop?

THanks for any pointers

osu

Answer (score 2):

I did this in a relatively complicated way using a custom query. I did not know about Smart Archives Reloaded so I wrote code myself. But it works. Replace your category ID for "term_taxonomy.term_id"

```
<?php
                     global $wpdb, $wp_locale;
                    $query = "select YEAR(post_date) AS `year`, MONTH(post_date) AS `month`, count(ID) as posts from $wpdb->posts,  $wpdb->term_taxonomy, $wpdb->term_relationships 
                        WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
                        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
                        AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 11
                        AND $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
                        AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
                     GROUP BY YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date) ORDER BY post_date DESC"; 
                     $arcresults = $wpdb->get_results($query); 
                    foreach ($arcresults as $arcresult): 
                    $text = sprintf(__('%1$s %2$d'), $wp_locale->get_month($arcresult->month), $arcresult->year);?>
                    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/[your_category_base]/[your_category_name]/date/<?php echo $arcresult->year; ?>/<?php echo str_pad($arcresult->month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>"><?php echo $text;  ?> </li>
                      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Writing this I was helped by looking at http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/general-template.php where wp_get_archives is defined.

And used the code found here (put in functions.php):
http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=17432
to create permalinks for archives for one category in the form of
http://example.com/category_base/category_name/date/YYYY/MM

Comment: I could not figure out how to make the url work the way you have it set up. I am not sure what to put in for category base.

I ended up with www.url.com?cat=9&m=<?php echo $year.$month;?>

it registers in the address bar as www.url.com/2014/04?cat=9

I would like to use the url that you have listed though. Do you have any hints for me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Scribu's [**Smart Archives Reloaded plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smart-archives-reloaded/) 
which allows you to display a list of posts grouped by year and month.

And to limit the archives by category is as simple as this:

```
smart_archives( '', 'category_name=category_name' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use query_posts to generate your query and then use a custom loop.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts